# ignoring warning "-Wunused-result"

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I am new to c++.

I want to ignore warning `-Wunused-result` which I guess popped because of `-Wall` flag.

I did search on net and found that this is I can ignore it by declaring a `pragma`. I don't have much knowledge about `pragma` but it says that I have to write `warning number` in order to ignore it.

What is `warning number` of `-Wunused-result`, or **is there any other way I can ignore or disable this specific warning?**

code:-

```
freopen("input", "r", stdin);
freopen("output", "a", stdout);
```

on compiling:-

```
warning: ignoring return value of ‘FILE* freopen(const char*, const char*, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

I found that I need to declare something like

`#pragma warning( disable : number_of_warning )`

Comment: Pro-tip: you generally don't want to *ignore* warnings. You want to *fix* them. In most cases they point to real problems in your code that you want to handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the return value of a function is to ignored, then one portable-ish way is to mark it with `void` as:

```
  (void) frepoen("input", "r", stdin);
```

It is a clear indication to both the reader as well as the compiler that the return value is really not necessary.

However, if a file is re-opened (`freopen`), then isn't the return value (`FILE *`) necessary for subsequent read/write operations on the file?

As Striezel pointed out, for stdin and stdout, althught the return value is not necessary for subsequent file operation, it may still be necessary for error checking. Upon failure, `freopen` returns NULL.

Comment: I am using g++ 5.4, and casting the return value to void isn't helping. I still get the warning.

Comment: I suppose this answer may have helped the asker, but there should be an answer which is general to the question in the title.

Comment: This doesn't work on g++ (the compiler the OP asked about as its about c++ and gcc is tagged). I guess it works in pure C?

Answer (score 24):

As the other answers say these warnings are usually for a good reason.

But if you need to suppress warnings caused by `__attribute__ ((__warn_unused_result__))` in gcc the usual simple cast to void does not work.

What does work is:

```
(void)!freopen("input", "r", stdin);
```

That `(void)` alone isn't enough is on purpose according to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66425
The workaround is from [comment 34](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66425#c34) in that bug report.

Comment: I suggest putting the workaround from comment 34 into your answer so it is self-contained.

Comment: The example code in my answer is using exactly that workaround. The link is just the link to the source where i got that workaround.

Comment: Oops, sorry!  I did not see the `!` in your answer; I only saw it when I clicked through.  That's my fault; I read it too fast.  But I notice that the example at the link has a helpful comment pointing to the `!`.  Perhaps you could add that to your answer as well?

Comment: This works in modern gcc. Very handy for ignoring some return values without turning off unused warnings completely. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have several options:

1. Just ignore the warning. Meaning, do nothing and just close your eyes whenever it pops up on your screen.
2. Tell your compiler to not emit the warning (haven't checked this specific one, but in most cases you can pass `-Wno-<warning-in-question>` (or use a `pragma`).
3. Cast the return value to `void` if you *really* want to ignore it (you probably don't).
4. Fix the actual problem by actually *using* the variable/return value (probably what you *actually* want).

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to the other answers - this question is tagged C++, and the others use a C-style cast.  For C++, use a `static_cast` to ignore the return type:

```cpp
static_cast<void>(...);
```

In this case:

```cpp
static_cast<void>(freopen("input", "r", stdin));
```